# Is back navigation on webview in a frame possible?

Tags: webview, uwp, windows-10, frame

In my Windows 10 UWP app I use the MainPage for a navigation hamburger menu. All other pages are loaded into a Frame on MainPage called MyFrame. With the following code, back navigation within this frame works perfectly:

```cs
private void MainPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        MyFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

However one of those pages contains a WebView. When this page is loaded, i want the webview instead of the frame to perform the GoBack Event.

Is it somehow possible to access the WebView's CanGoBack property from MainPage?

edit: maybe something like this works?

```
    private void MainPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyFrame.Content == typeof(Web))
        {
            get state of the Webview "SearchURI" here and handle the GoBack event
        }
        else if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            MyFrame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible. The back pressed event is app-wide, thus this may depend on the way how you subscribe to it. Can you elaborate more how and where you subscribe to this event?

Comment: Generally you have to recognize in the back event that you have the WebView opened, you can do it by a flag or by another subscription the the event and setting e.Handled to true, then in other event check if it's already handled. Also remember to change behavior back once you leave the WebView page.

Comment: The page containing the WebView is called "Web". I have to supress the MyFrame.GoBack Event, maybe with something like this:

        private void MainPage_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MyFrame.Content == typeof(Web))
            {
                 do back Navigation inside the WebView "SearchURI" here
            }
            else if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                MyFrame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

Comment: Something like this may work, however I can't see BackPressed for the Page class, what template are you using? This may vary depending on the way the event is handled in the behind, however you simple way may work.

Comment: Those are my very first steps in terms of app development, i only know the simple stuff ;) But i do not know how to access the state of the "SearchURI" from MainPage.

Comment: You will have to expose parameter, also binding may be helpful here. Another simple way may be to use *static* value.

Comment: So, if I declare an internal Webview in App.xaml.cs for example?

internal static WebView InternalWV;

Comment: I wouldn't do this like this - making static control, this doesn't bode well. Instead use some kind of variable which you can set when you open/use your WebView - then check that variable when using back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebView` already has `CanGoBack` Property and `GoBack` Method for you to use. Using these methods, you can use `BackButton` and control your backkeyprocess.

Below is how I would do it.

In your `Web.xaml.cs` Declare a public variable

```cs
public WebView myWebView { get; private set; }
```

and in your page constructor, assign the actual `WebView` reference to this variable.

```cs
public Web()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    myWebView = this.webView;
}
```

Now in you `MainPage.xaml.cs`, The button where you use to navigate, Subscribe to `BackRequested`

```cs
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
```

And now your `OnnackRequested` will show something like below.

```cs
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyFrame.Content.GetType() == typeof(Web))
    {
        Web web = MyFrame.Content as Web;
        if (web.myWebView.CanGoBack)
        {
            web.myWebView.GoBack();
        }
        else
        {
            if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MyFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unless the webview navigates back to your initial page, you will not be able to go back to the previous page that is loaded in your `MyFrame`

Good Luck.

Comment: This is great! Thank you, thats exacly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: @Sebastian, If this helped, Please mark it as an answer.